# Which version to download 4.4.1 or 4.5?

Tags: xcode

[Apple_app](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#)

I am really confused. The version 4.4.1 seems to be updated at 5 Dec 2012. while 4.5 seems to have been updated in Oct 2012 . Dates of updates seem to be confusing ! 
It's like an older version updated after a newer version. 
So which version should be downloaded ?

Vishwas

Comment: aggghhh, you made me go to an apple site.  Entirely objectively, it looks as if the 4.4.1 release is a bugfix to 4.4 which came out after 4.5 (the bugfix, that is).  My guess is some people are required to use 4.4 but needed a bug fixed that is either not present or not occuring in 4.5

Comment: This is not uncommon for compilers and similar software. You don't really have linear versions, but rather branches. Say 4.5 is released and introduces new features that break backwards compatibility. After that, a bug in 4.4 is discovered that needs to be fixed, but there are people whose codebase is incompatible to 4.5, so you need to provide an update to the 4.4 branch and call it 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always work on latest stable version of Xcode .So you should download the Xcode version 4.5.2